# Removing items in a list of list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Let's say I have a class named **Inventory**. **Inventory** has many **Products**. Each **Products** has many characteristics like **Size** or a list of **Colors**.

I want to remove all the Colors of my Hats in the inventory. I was wondering if it is possible within 1 line using LINQ instead of using a loop.

```
inventory.Products.Where(x=>x.name.ToLower() == "hats").SelectMany(x=> x.Colors)
```

This is as much as I could get for now.

Thanks !

Comment: You want to _remove_ or _select_?

Comment: Clear the list of colors for every product named hats

Comment: LINQ is for querying, not for modifying data

Comment: Maybe I used the term LINQ in the wrong sense. If so, i'm sorry for the confusion it may bring to the conversation.

Comment: LINQ is not a term, it's a library. The best you can do is `var hats = inventory.Products.Where(x=>x.name.ToLower() == "hats");` and foreach over that

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto LINQ is fine to use instead of ugly foreach blocks since it can make code more readable

Comment: @lionthefox Your answer *does not* use LINQ to remove the elements, it uses a `List<T>` method

Comment: @MichaëlCorriveau-Côté I don't agree with him here, it does exactly the same but is a lot more code and less readable

Comment: Why do you want to do this all in one line? It would become hard to debug / read? Use abstraction and you can keep your code clean without the need to nest operations into one line.

Comment: @lionthefox A lot more code? A foreach? To avoid creating an unneeded List, loop the elements **once** (and not **twice**) and so gain performance? Wow

Comment: @lionthefox gave me the answer I was looking for. I edited the title too. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Some people just like writing slower, more complex, more error prone, slower, and more memory consuming code, so that they get to use fancy looking features.  That's their choice to make.

Comment: @MichaëlCorriveau-Côté Well lit's not answering the question you asked for, even if it was the answer you wanted, in addition to being a bad idea.

Comment: @Servy is the answer provided not a good solution to my original problem?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto you are right, but if you read the question you will notice that he wanted to do it in a single line.

Comment: @lionthefox Sure, *that's* more important

Comment: @MichaëlCorriveau-Côté No.  It creates an entirely new list entirely unnecessarily, using lots of additional memory and time.  All so that a `List` method (not a LINQ method) could be used to do something a language feature already specifically exists to do (perform an action on each item in a sequence).

Comment: @lionthefox You can use a `foreach` loop in one line of code.  There's no reason to duplicate an entire list just to do something on one line.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto it's exactly what he asked for. I know it's not the most performant and efficient way but he didn't ask to make it most efficient, did he?

Comment: @lionthefox Exactly what was asked for was a LINQ solution, which you didn't provide. (Although that would be a bad idea too, because LINQ is for querying, not for performing actions on items in a sequence.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you so much want a one-liner, you should use this:

```
foreach (var product in inventory.Products.Where(x => x.name.ToLower() == "hats")) { product.Colors.Clear(); }
```

LINQ is a library for querying data, not for altering it. Balancing LINQ and language features here is *much* better than going "one line LINQ only" for no reason.

Comment: I didn't notice i was using an extension function and not LINQ's .ForEach(). This should be the accepted answer. Take my upvote, for i just learned something :)